# This version does not support collection view cell content view. Open this document with at least Xcode 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, beta, xcode11

I was excited to check out Xcode 11 with my existing xCode project, so I started coding with the latest beta version. Today I wanted to upload my new app update but of course Apple rejected the binaries advising me, to use a GM version of Xcode 11 (not released yet) or the latest Xcode 10 app.

I was able to revert all changes made by Xcode 11 (provisioning profile, etc.) and opened the project back in Xcode 10 but I stuck in an error saying

> This version does not support collection view cell content view. Open
>   this document with at least Xcode 11.0.

I am not able to build, archive or even open the storyboard in xCode 10. I found a single collection view in my storyboard in Xcode 11 which I created using the beta. But also after deleting the entire UICollectionViewController incl. the cells and cleaning the project, I am not able open the storyboard back in Xcode 10.

Comment: Revert your project to the revision in your source code control system from just before you upgraded to Xcode 11. You have got your project under source code control, haven't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open the storyboard file with a text editor and search for the property. Usually when there is a warning, Xcode will show this warning during compile time. See if double-clicking the warning redirects you to the line of code where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 9):

I've read accepted answer, but it wasn't obvious where to find "property" which could be just switched off or something like.

To make it more clear: you just need to replace all occurencies of `collectionViewCellContentView` with `view` in storyboard source code. For example see screenshot:

[image: Storyboard source code]

Next, rebuild and Xcode will remove `<capability name="collection view cell content view" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>` requirement; or remove it manually if you're using Xcode 10.

Hope will be helpful.

**EDIT**

Found how to "switch off" using of collection view cell content view, but you'll still need Xcode 11 to open storyboard. Change size to `Default` in collection view cell prototype size inspector:

[image: Switch off content view]

Comment: @Rob thanks for advice. I've considered rule you refer to, and I think it doesn't fit quite directly. Rule tells to provide code as a text to help others work with it, but the only things required are strings to find and replace, which are posted in a paragraph above, while screenshot only helps to recognise right place. Though code on screenshot could be represented as a text, I decided that diff screenshot from cvs better shows what was changed, so I think it's still a valid illustration.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your storyboard which is not opening. Right click on it , Open it with Source Code and search for the property which is not allowing xcode to open your Storyboard.

Search for the property e.g "*collection view content view*".

Delete that property block. Now Open your Story board as an **Interface Builder**.

Note: By Deleting the property you will lost that in your view controller screen. :)